# Why are network speeds reported by Activity Monitor different than the ones reported by speedtest.net?

Tags: macos, network

When I run a test on speedtest.net, I get 90Mbps for download and 35Mbps for upload.

Looking at Activity Monitor I see 50 MB/s and 17.5MB/s.

My understanding is that 1Mbps equals 0.125MB/s.

Why is there a discrepancy?

Comment: How do you get Activity Monitor to show transmission in MB/s? I don't see that. The answer is probably that they use different averaging, but I can't test.

Comment: @Tetsujin In Activity Monitor (Catalina), in the Network tab, bottom right... Data sent and received/sec in KB or MB (adjusted to current throughput).

Comment: Ah, yup, found it. Yes, it's using totally different averaging method. It's not examining the exact start & stop point that Speedtest is, it's just doing an average over the past perhaps 5 seconds. I got 217mbps Speedtest, 20MB/s Activity Monitor. It took it at least 2 updates to even reach that, by which time Speedtest had just about finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's using a totally different averaging method.
It's not examining the exact start & stop point that Speedtest is, it's just doing an average over the past 5 seconds.

I got 217mbps Speedtest, 20MB/s Activity Monitor. It took it at least 2 updates to even reach that, by which time Speedtest had just about finished.

Switching Activity Monitor from its default 5 second update to just 1 second* & the values just about match - I was getting 217mbps Speedtest with 27MB/s Activity Monitor (roughly).

Also bear in mind you are comparing a one-trick pony - an app dedicated to providing line speed results - against one that's more a general overview of what your entire machine is doing.

*After comments*
As there was still a discrepancy at 1s sampling, try to eliminate sources of error - switch from WiFi to wired Ethernet; remove any VPN connections; test another account or Mac.

*View menu > Update Frequency

Comment: Thanks! What about the 17.5MB/s vs 35Mbps? My connection cannot go faster than 40Mbps upstream... Wouldn't 17.5MB/s equate to 140Mbps?

Comment: Test it again on a 1s update

Comment: Done... Somehow speeds in Activity Monitor appear to be half of what they are on speedtest.net. I don't understand the maths. Do you know why? Btw speeds are reported correctly in MB/s by Little Snitch.

Comment: I can't explain that discrepancy. Mine matches (approximately) in both directions. If you're on wifi, wire up to eliminate that as the cause.

Comment: As mentioned, Little Snitch reports the speeds accurately so it isn't a Wi-Fi issue... perhaps it's a VPN issue though. Now I know it's specific to my setup. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I ran the same test on another computer with a "vanilla" macOS install and the discrepancy isn't present. This confirms the issue is specific to my setup (hardened macOS with strongSwan VPN). Should have tried that first.

Comment: Would you mind adding the above to your answer? I will accept it. Btw, I can edit your answer if you prefer. I believe "wire up to eliminate that as the cause" or "run test on a default install" adds value to the answer.